# Conference: Will you attend the Tridion Developer Summit 2014, 15 May, Amsterdam

Tags: discussion

The first Tridion Developer Conference is happening on 15 May in Amsterdam.  We have many of the top Tridion StackExchange users as speakers on new and interesting Tridion topics.  To find out more see http://www.tridiondevelopersummit.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wouldn't miss it! ..............

Answer (score 3):

I will definitely attend, and not only attend, I will step up on the stage and say something too...

What I will say? Well that will remain a secret for now ;o)

Answer (score 2):

Of course, I will.

I only wish I had some topic to talk upon.